# Optparse and sys.argv - Python

Tags: python, linux

i've written a python script, that accepts input via the `optparse` module of python.
and I take input from `sys.argv` as well.

When I use either of them, the program works correctly. For example:

```
python dperf.py -m 1 -c 2 -n 3
python dperf.py foobar
```

However, it does not when I give the input in this manner.

```
python dperf.py foobar -m 1 -c 2 -n 3
```

Is there a mistake in the way I am using `sys.argv`?

```
parser = optparse.OptionParser()
#migration
parser.add_option("-m", type="float", dest="migr")
#collection
parser.add_option("-c", type="float", dest="coll")
#num of lines to read
parser.add_option("-n", type="float", dest="fileread")
(options, args) = parser.parse_args()

ti =  options.migr
colle =  options.coll
linereadfiles =  options.fileread

apps = sys.argv[1:]
```

Comment: For new development work, take a look at [`argparse`](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/argparse.html) since [`optparse`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/optparse) is deprecated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you parse options via the `parse_args()` of the `OptionParser`, do not use `sys.argv` directly but the returned `args` instead which should contain the parts not already parsed by the `OptionParser`.

For example in your code replace

```
 apps = sys.argv[1:]
```

by

```
apps = args
```

(or just scrap the `apps` and go on with `args`).

Comment: can you give a short example please?

Comment: Question: Should I change the question title to be more apt. or was it apt enough?

Comment: For me it needs no editing, but if you feel like it, maybe mention OptionParser in the title, too, if you think that this would improve it.